# Selenium WebDriver executeScript not working

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using the script to set the value of the hidden form field variable `formContent` to the value 'Hello'. Selenium Webdriver doesn't set the value of the hidden form field as it is not visible.

Here is my code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return jQuery('input:hidden[id$=\"formContent\"]').val('Hello');");
```

I am getting the script is unresponsive. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong here. The `formContent` is defined in my xhtml as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="formContent" name="formContent" value="" />
```

If use the following lines of code, then it is not setting the value of the hidden form field "formContent":

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("jQuery('input:hidden[id$=\"formContent\"]').val('Hello');");
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you intend for the script to do

Comment: I am using the script to set the value of the hidden form field variable formContent to the value 'Hello'. Selenium Webdriver doesnt set the value of the hidden form field as it is not visible.

Comment: Please check whether it works with an 'alert'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a bug with the Firefox webdriver. I experienced something similar when trying to return jQuery objects and described the behavior here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3756

Try returning something other than a jQuery obj, and it should become responsive again. For example, you could return a boolean value of your executed code by just prefixing it with !! like this:

```
js.executeScript("return !!jQuery('input:hidden[id$=\"formContent\"]').val('Hello');");
```